# .replaceWith messes up the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

For learning reasons, I build my own link shortener and yeah...
After 5 Seconds this code

```
<div class="skip-container">
    <p class="five">SKIP IN 5 SECONDS</p>
</div>
```

should be replaced with

```
<div class="skip-button">
    <a href="PHP CODE" class="js-skip-button">SKIP THIS AD</a>  
    <div class="skip-arrow"></div> 
</div>
```

to do that I tried

```
$( document ).ready(function test() {
    setTimeout(function test() {
        $("p.five").replaceWith('<div class="skip-button">
        <a href="PHP CODE" class="js-skip-button">SKIP THIS AD</a>  
        <div class="skip-arrow"></div>  </div> ');
    }, 5000);
});
```

It changed the script, but it looks broken and not like how it should... I read something about it keeps it in DOM and such stuff, but I am new in all that and yeah... https://viid.su/bBwgN is the problem page!

Comment: ES5 does not have multi-line strings; your JS console will indicate your syntax error.

Comment: @DaveNewton: No version of JavaScript has unescaped multi-line *strings*. :-) ES2015+ has *template literals*, which evaluate to strings (unless a tag function is applied to them that does something else).

Comment: there ks mp error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to concatenate the string down, or escape the new lines:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("p.five").replaceWith('<div class="skip-button">\
                                 <a href="PHP CODE" class="js-skip-button">SKIP THIS AD</a>\
                                 <div class="skip-arrow"></div>\
                             </div> ');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Check for odd whitespace when copying: https://jsfiddle.net/wnnpmg28/1/

Comment: @I.Dynin: Not anymore, there were just a couple of extra spaces on one of the lines; Ben's fixed it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Didn't spot the odd whitespace in the answer (hence the comment about odd whitespace when copying ;) )

Comment: BenM check the site

Comment: ok the edited version works better, but is still not how it shoud be